# host vs name for domain information

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-route53, godaddy

Is there a difference in the terms "host" vs "name" when talking about records for routing? I have an account with GoDaddy but but all my DNS management onto Route 53. Then I just purchased email through GoDaddy and am setting up the records. When it says host/name are these the same things? I don't see anywhere in Route 53 to add a host so, I assume yes?

[image]
[image]

Comment: The DNS (RFC 1034/1035) specifies only "domain name" (any name with any character; not to be confused with "domain name" in the registration sense which one is more like "hostname" in DNS, see after), and "hostname" which is a subset as it can be only with letter, digits and hypens. Some records allow only hostnames like `A` or `AAAA`, not domain names.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek so..... when GoDaddy says Host do they mean Record Name in Route 53 context?

Comment: I don't know, but why do you seem to handle DNS records both on GoDaddy side and on Route53 side? This won't work, you need to decide once for all who is your DNS provider, use its nameservers, and use its API/UI to mutate content of your zone. `TXT` and `CNAME` records can be attached to random domain names (in the DNS sense), while `A` and `AAAA` records can be only attached to hostnanes.

Comment: Also "routing policy" is not among the DNS standard, this is a specific feature of a given DNS provider so you will need to ask it directly on what it means and its consequences.

Comment: I only handle DNS records on Route 53. These are instructions from GoDaddy on how to setup your email if they are not managing your DNS records.